# How to collect second line to second to last line of an ouput?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

I'm sending a get_errors command through my python script to a terminal window and I want to collect/return the second line all the way to the second to last line that the command outputs. When run the command manually, I see something like this:

```
(Shell):fpga) get_errors_counter 0
OK: argList is:  [0]
Channel 0 error count = 0
Channel 1 error count = 0
Channel 2 error count = 0
Channel 3 error count = 0
(Shell):fpga)
```

What I want is the output that starts at Channel 0 to the last value of Channel 3 (there is a chance the error value won't be 0 every time, though it will be Channel 0-3 every time).

Normally I use "output = tn.read_until(stuff)", but this time it's a little more complicated and I'm not sure what to put for 'stuff' this time around.

Comment: What is `get_errors_counter` in this case?

Comment: that is the command I type/send to get the error count from Channels 0-3

Comment: Right, but what is that command? Sorry if my question wasn't clear, I'm trying to figure out where/how you're running this.